# yt-dlp: How to download best m4a?

Tags: homebrew, youtube

How can I download best quality m4a using yt-dlp?

On YouTube-dl I did it with this command:
`youtube-dl -f bestaudio[ext=m4a] URL`

But on yt-dlp this command gives me error, `no matches found: bestaudio[ext=m4a].`

What am I doing wrong, how can I modify this commands to work with yt-dlp?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about Apple hardware or software within the scope defined in the [help centre](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: To throw you a bone, don't bother with cli yt-dl implementations, just get JDownloader. It can sniff copied URLs & then extract whatever you want - https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ct5p.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are being caught out by `zsh` and its interpretation of the command before passing parameters to `yt-dlp`. It's actually `zsh` throwing the error. Put quotes round your parameters. Also, be sure to quote your URL too, especially on `zsh`.

`yt-dlp -f 'bestaudio[ext=m4a]' 'URL'`